# Problem when request HTTP post request using py

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a problem when requesting a POST request from this API: https://docs.pixe.la/entry/post-user

```
import requests as re
url = 'https://pixe.la/v1/users'
myobj =({"token":"tonybui", 
        "username":"Tonybui2003", 
        "agreeTermsOfService":"yes", 
        "notMinor":"yes"})
        
# {"message":"Success. Let's visit https://pixe.la/@a-know , it is your profile page!","isSuccess":true}
response = re.post(url, data = myobj)

# data = response.json()
print(response.text)
```

Error message: `{"message":"Failed to unmarshal request body: invalid character 'o' in literal true (expecting 'r')","isSuccess":false}`

Comment: Try to put everything in myobj on one line, using `'` in stead of `()`, Like: `myobj ='{"token":"tonybui", "username":"Tonybui2003", "agreeTermsOfService":"yes", "notMinor":"yes"}'`.    I do receive this: `{"message":"The token string must be at least 8 characters and not more than 128 letters and numbers or alphanumeric characters or symbols.","isSuccess":false}`

Comment: `response = re.post(url, json = myobj)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `data = myobj` in **response** variable use `json = myobj`

**Remove the parentheses in myobj variable**